# How do I get to the laboratory for Scent of Incense?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm working on the Scent of Incense quest in Flotsam (Chapter 1). I got the real recipe and talked with the scholar. I refused to be blindfolded, so he marked the location of his laboratory on my map.

Unfortunately, I can get close to the marker, but I can't seem to find a way to actually reach it. I've gone up and down the path with the two bandit groups (the way to the field full of Kayran mucus.

I also tried searching around the other path in the area, which leads to the graveyard area a little ways outside town. All to no avail.

How do I get to the laboratory and get my reward?

Comment: I let myself be blindfolded, but I remember that it was a cave that was a bit uphill. I don't think you have to go up the path with the bandits, the path to the laboratory branches out somewhere at the foot of the hill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The laboratory is in a cave, and the entrance is nowhere near the marker on the map.

Exit town along the south-east path.[image: Leaving town]

Go left, toward the big rock face.[image: Go left]

Ta-da! Cave.[image: Cave]

This is the location of the cave entrance on the map.[image: Mappity map]

Comment: I'm playing the game already, but am still amazed at how gorgeous the screens look.

Comment: @Bora It does look nice, but I'm hoping there are some brighter areas later on. So far it's nothing but dark forest and blue light everywhere. I need some color!

Comment: I suppose this cave is sealed after the quest? I opted to be blindfolded and now want to go back there to take a look but the it's all rocky cliff side; no cave in that area.